# docker on ubuntu 16.04 error when killing container

Tags: docker, docker-container

I can't kill or stop any docker container. I've allowed non-privileged users to run Docker commands. And `docker run hello-world` works fine.
But I can't stop any other container.

I got following:

```
$ docker stop 59e3b815d1dc
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 59e3b815d1dc: 
Cannot kill container 59e3b815d1dcf2d8c8bcd3dd641c3c033b83ac68ea2f0257a32a76468af7374c: 
unknown error after kill: docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: 
container_linux.go:393: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
```

The same error with sudo. Meanwhile, all containers run successfully, but to stop them is possible only a full reboot of the system.

Docker compose example:
    # Use postgres/example user/password credentials
    version: '3.1'

```
services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Docker info:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 7
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 5
Images: 10
Server Version: 17.12.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9b55aab90508bd389d7654c4baf173a981477d55
runc version: 9f9c96235cc97674e935002fc3d78361b696a69e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-116-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 11.61GiB
Name: peter-pen
ID: P6FS:C76H:WIAO:LCWC:TCHT:JEYB:6W3M:HXYD:S4E2:KTUZ:2T3Q:3GPI
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: It's probably AppArmor. Maybe you installed the Ubuntu Docker packages then the Docker one and the profiles got mixed up?

Comment: There were docker and docker-engine but I've purged they. The "permission denied" error was with that packages too and I decided to install docker considered with official manual.

Comment: @Matt I'll look at AppArmor later, thanks for direction

Comment: It was AppArmor

Comment: @Petr how did you fix AppArmor?

Comment: @MichalCiechan It's not the better way, but I disabled AppArmor for Docker

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AppArmor (Application Armor) is a Linux security module that protects an operating system and its applications from security threats. To use it, a system administrator associates an AppArmor security profile with each program. Docker expects to find an AppArmor policy loaded and enforced. Check default profiles with:

```
# sudo apparmor_status
```

To use docker default profile on a container, run:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --name test-container --security-opt apparmor=docker-default image-name
```

You disable it using the commands:

```
--security-opt apparmor=unconfined
```

With the docker run commands.

To disable apparmor service, use:

```
# systemctl stop apparmor && systemctl disable apparmor
```

For Ubuntu 14. Use:

```
# service apparmor stop
# update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
```

It’s recommended to set working profiles for Docker apparmor than disabling it, especially for production setups.

Check this awesome google document on Securing Containers with AppArmor.

https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/secure-apparmor

Comment: Is there a specific thing I can do while building an image to avoid the issue of not being able to stop a container when running it? I'm asking because I've noticed that there are specific images that causes this issue, while others on the same system don't.

Answer (score 149):

For me removing the unknown from AppArmor works:

```
sudo aa-remove-unknown
```

Comment: It works! but I'm wondering where is the magic behind this command ?

Comment: I mount a docker service on Windows NTFS and it failed to stop, using this command works, but I still need to know the reason behind.

Comment: This link had some discussion about what this is: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/

Comment: I want to know behind the scenes work of "sudo aa-remove-unknown". Yes it solved my issue but how?

Comment: This seems to have messed up my install of multiple things. Beware.

`snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks`

Comment: Rebooting seems to have fixed my issues.

Answer (score 12):

This command will stop all docker containers.

```
sudo killall docker-containerd-shim
```

This command will remove all docker containers.

```
sudo docker-compose down
```

Comment: Why would the OP do that? Explain what these commands do and why it might help

Comment: My mind blown, Thank you so much, it worked awesome :)

Answer (score 7):

Just run this command in the terminal, all docker running container will stoped

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

Answer (score 2):

**Follow these steps to be able to stop the container:**

Disable the apparmor service:

```
sudo systemctl disable apparmor.service --now
```

Unload AppArmor profiles:

`sudo service apparmor teardown`

Check AppArmor status:

`sudo aa-status`

You should be able to stop and kill your container now.

[Credits](https://jboka.de/2018/10/08/docker-apparmor-error-solution.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible this was caused by Ubuntu's security and in particular [apparmor](https://apparmor.net/) In that case, **you can of course remove your system's security, but that seems drastic**. Plus, there seems to be going on some patching to  docker that will solve all issues soon.

In the mean time, you can add to the `docker run` command the option `--security-opt apparmor:unconfined`. This seems preferable to removing apparmor.

e.g. try:

```
docker run --security-opt apparmor:unconfined -ti ubuntu bash
```

then try to `docker stop` and see everything now works!

You will unfortunately have to manually stop already running dockerfiles just this once unless you reboot. One (drastic) option to do that is by running:

```
sudo killall -9 docker
sudo killall -9 dockerd
```

To make things easier, "alias" docker... You need to make sure the parameters go to the right place e.g.

```
# in your ~/.bash_profile (~/.profile for ubuntu)
docker()
{
  if [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ "$1" == "run" ] ; then
     shift
     docker run --security-opt apparmor:unconfined "$@"
  else
     command docker "$@"
  fi
}
```

Then source `~/.profile`

Answer (score 0):

After using the below commands I was able to use `docker-compose stop` again:

```sh
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove apparmor
sudo service docker restart
docker system prune --all --volumes
```

Comment: it removes all the snap installation

Comment: It is going to cause serious consequences for your system. Don't try it until you fully understand what are you going to do.