# docker compose down fails due to "permission denied"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

On running `docker-compose stop` it fails to stop the docker images, and gives an error like this:

`ERROR: for nginx cannot stop container: 5f5ed6d2110a0d845508ede160d8196d3e01f1d677e22e4944adc8c984800cff: Cannot kill container 
5f5ed6d2110a0d845508ede160d8196d3e01f1d677e22e4944adc8c984800cff: Unknown error after kill: docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:393: signaling init process caused "Permission Denied": unknown`

The images are still running properly, they just don't restart. I am running `docker-compose` on Ubuntu.

Comment: do you test with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes I did test with `sudo` but it gave the same error.

Comment: A very nice clear answer for me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49573618/7010923

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem by running:

```
sudo killall docker-containerd-shim
```

And then `docker-compose down` started working for me.

I found the solution in [this bug report](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36010), and it seems that it involves a backport of a fix to the runc code.

EDIT

It seems that the root cause of these problems on my system was the Docker snap image on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. I completely removed the snap image and reinstalled Docker using https://get.docker.io, and I no longer encounter these problems. In the meantime, the rest of my answer above worked for me as a workaround.

Comment: I think it's now `containerd-shim`, at least in my version.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104733/docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-error-when-killing-container/49573618#49573618. Eddy's solution worked for me in 18.10 as well. snap remove docker.

Comment: Confirmed, docker installed through snap is known to have some quirks and issues that do not affect other installation methods.  I was also getting the "permission denied" error and had to rip out docker engine and docker compose.  I got things to work by reinstalling the engine using the link below, and then using the docker compose plugin.


https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

Answer (score 19):

Somehow this worked for me.

```
$ sudo killall containerd-shim
```

Comment: thanx so much, this one saved me !!

Answer (score 10):

2021: in my case, I am using the

```
sudo aa-remove-unknown
```

then, run

```
sudo docker-compose down
```

then, the application down successfully

Comment: That worked for me even without `sudo`: `docker-compose down`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what helped me was to kill all of my containers, delete all of my images and data volumes, and start over.

If you have no problem **DELETING** all of your data volumes and all of your unused images, you can try these two commands:

```
sudo service docker restart
docker system prune --all --volumes
```

Answer (score 0):

There is such a solution. 
Stop and restart docker services

```
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

After check -> `docker ps`
if cant be deleted to containers then try this -> `docker container rm container_name --force`

Ports may not have been deleted. this will cause conflict. 
Find used port PID -> `sudo lsof -i:port`
and kill `sudo kill -9 PID`