# docker on ubuntu 16.04 error when stopping container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers, docker-container, apparmor

I'm totally new with Docker and tried to create my first container from an image I built from my aspnetcore project.

The image was built, I could started a container but I want to change some things so I need to remove this container.

Problems arrived from this step. I tried to stop it or remove it by force but I had each time but I had exactly the same message than this question :
[docker on ubuntu 16.04 error when killing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104733/docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-error-when-killing-container)

I have the same same OS but a newer version of docker.

In the answer of this question I don't understand how to stop the container.

I heard about apparmor but I don't know what to do with it to be able to remove this container.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: try `sudo docker container stop "your_container_id"`.list  your running containers Id using `sudo docker container ls` and get container Id from there.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and I have the same message

Comment: are you sure, that you installed `docker correctly`.hence you are in the beginning I suggest you to `reinstall` **docker**. this link will guid you : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Hello, sorry for being late, I tried to reinstall docker with the link you sent and I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reloaded a backup of my VM, re-install docker and all is good