# Docker unable to stop container

Tags: docker

I am using docker version `Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4` in a `Ubuntu 16.04 system`. I am unable to stop a docker container. My docker image contains a spring boot application. I am using the following command to stop the container:

`sudo docker stop 0c6b70fcb25e`

And I am getting the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 0c6b70fcb25e: 
Cannot kill container 0c6b70fcb25e0b0c55f123853654cd2611e3702fdf5622bd07e12a92efa3df46: 
unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully:
container_linux.go:393: signaling init process caused "permission denied": unknown
```

I have tried running **docker stop** with and without **sudo.**

Comment: Can you say anything about what the container is; for instance, how you started it?

Comment: @DavidMaze I edited my question with more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker on ubuntu 16.04 error when killing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104733/docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-error-when-killing-container)

Comment: @PeterHalligan The question seems to be related to docker-compose. I am not using docker-compose.

Comment: The issue affects  users both with and without compose

Comment: This might help also https://forums.docker.com/t/can-not-stop-docker-container-permission-denied-error/41142

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker kill --signal=SIGHUP my_container
```

You can find more information [here.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/)

Also, if you are on Linux, AppArmor may prevent stopping the containers. Disable AppArmor temporarily and try to stop the container again. For configuring the AppArmor check this [link.](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/secure-apparmor)

Comment: I tried it out and I am still getting the same response. :(

Comment: If you are on Linux, get the PID and use "kill -9 PID"

Comment: killing the process worked, but isn't that the wrong way? What is the issue with **docker stop?**

Comment: Yes, it is the wrong way. Check this link https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/secure-apparmor to use AppArmor with the Docker containers.

Comment: Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link. [docker on ubuntu 16.04 error when killing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104733/docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-error-when-killing-container/49573618#49573618)

I used the following commands and it worked.

```
sudo killall docker-containerd-shim

sudo docker-compose down
```